# removing an object from arraylist without changing the index of other objects

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

So i need to delete a specific object under the index number of how many times my loop has passed in an arraylist.

lets say i want to delete my object that has an index 0 on arraylist

but the object on index 1 and index 2 (and so on) still need to be the same index number as before i removed index 0.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4 i++) {
            player thisPlayer = players.get(i);

            if (not important) {
                players.remove(thisPlayer);
            }
        }
```

if player 1 needs to be removed, the other players need to maintain the same index.

what do i do?

Comment: You could set the value at that element to `null`. Removing elements, except when removing from the end, will shift other elements forward, as you probably know.

Comment: You could store the elements in a `Map<Integer, Player>`; then you can remove arbitrary elements (and keys) without effecting other keys.

Comment: Is it actually important that the index remains unchanged **after** the loop is finished, or is it just important to make the loop work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, Using Iterator to search an ArrayList and delete matching objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174964/java-using-iterator-to-search-an-arraylist-and-delete-matching-objects)

Comment: i believe your best choice is to use a map as @ElliottFrisch said

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using

```
players.remove(thisPlayer);
```

You could try something along the lines of

```
players.set(players.indexOf(thisPlayer),null);
```

Comment: my idea was very similary to this, just instead of null, I'd put some dummy player or something